# How to upload phone backup Call/sms/contacts to google cloud

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

I am new and just started in `Android`. I want to upload phonebackup data of call/sms/contacts to `Google Cloud` or `Google Drive`. I know how to create write these content data in `SDCARD` but unable to upload on Google cloud.

[Link I already tried](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/)

In this i downloded sample project app but it require

```
com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo.BaseDemoActivity.EXISTING_FOLDER_ID
com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo.BaseDemoActivity.EXISTING_FILE_ID
```

I have created `OAuth key` and `Public key` as [instructed here](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth)

But cant find these two key's anywhere too.

Can someone please guide me to solve my issue.

Thanks in advance.